# The input buffer of a Sample and Hold

Tags: buffer, sample-and-hold

[image]

In a Sample and Hold circuit, I know that the buffer amplifier after the capacitor keeps the capacitor from discharging because of its high impedance and causes the output voltage to be equal to the capacitor voltage.

But.. what is the function of the input buffer, why do we need it there?

Comment: To increase the input impedance. So that whatever voltage source is being measured doesn't have to charge up that capacitor, possibly affecting the signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the bare sample circuit presents a varying load to its input.  This means that if the impedance of the source driving the sample circuit is too high, then the sampling capacitor does not have time to settle out before the switch opens.

For the sampling stage that's pictured, this has the effect of reducing the stage's bandwidth, because the voltage on the cap immediately before the switch closes is basically what it was the last time the switch opened.  For something more complicated, like an ADC where the sampling is charging up a C-2C ladder, any residual voltage on the capacitor may be less predictable, and the resulting error introduced by a poorly-buffered signal would be worse than just low-pass filtering.